# Getter not found: 'context'. fontSize: MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context)*18,

Tags: flutter, flutter-design

**I want to make my font size responsive, but using MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context) does not solve the problem and even throws an error to the console which reads;**

```
Getter not found: 'context'.
fontSize: MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context)*18,
                                     ^^^^^^^
```

**below is my TextStyle code and it is in my build widget.**

```
Text(input, style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18 * MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context),
                  fontFamily: 'Calculator',
                  color: Color(0xFF46595C),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),),
```

Comment: Share the part of code where this occurs. It seems that you don't have a build context there.